# There seems to be no cloc in RHEL8 and clones

Tags: rhel

When I wanted to count the lines of code in a project, I am starting, I surprisingly found out that there is no cloc binary installed. I tried to install cloc rpm, and to my bigger surprise I was not able to find cloc el8 rpm.

Can anybody tell me, why is that so? Is there some new cloc alternative that should be used? Obviously I will have to install it from source. I am using Oracle Linux 8, and was not able to find cloc for RHEL8 or any alternative like CentOS, AlmaLinux, Rocky Linux, etc.

Comment: I just found out that cloc is actually a perl program, so no compilation of binary is needed. I just need to copy cloc file from https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc to some executable path like `/usr/local/bin`. However, that does not answer my question, why is it not included in the distribution any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think `cloc` has ever been included in RHEL itself; it’s [available in EPEL 7 and Fedora](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/cloc). Your best bet, if you want a package for RHEL 8 and clones, is to [file an EPEL package request for EPEL 8](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/epel-package-request/).